# javascript clickable area inside a square

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

So I am trying to add a class to a clickable area depending on where in that area the user clicks.

I have created this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aocgrp06/

now, the problem is with this bit of code:

```
if (coordinates.x < height/2 && coordinates.x < width-coordinates.y && coordinates.x < coordinates.y) {
    alert("top triangle");
}

if (coordinates.y > width/2 && coordinates.x > width-coordinates.y && coordinates.x < coordinates.y) {
    alert("right triangle");
}

if (coordinates.x > height/2 && coordinates.x > width-coordinates.y && coordinates.x > coordinates.y) {
    alert("bottom triangle");
}

if (coordinates.y < width/2 && coordinates.x < width-coordinates.y && coordinates.x > coordinates.y) {
    alert("left triangle");
}
```

it isn't working as I had hoped. As you can see from the fiddle, the square has coloured edges and then a center square. What I am trying to do is add a class the the element based on the click position. 
For example, if the user clicks the center square, then it will add the **center** class. Similarly, if they click the top border, it will add the **top** class to the element.

Has someone done something similar to this before? If so, could you please help me figure out the correct algorithm?

**Update**

So, now we have a new fiddle thanks to **A. Rama**.

http://jsfiddle.net/aocgrp06/5/

this works fine, apart from the centre box.
**Naeem Shaikh** suggested putting an extra div inside the box which doesn't allow propagation which would work, but it would also stop the link from working. I would prefer a pure javascript / jQuery solution, so if anyone can think of one, that would be awesome.

**Update 2**

So, because this hasn't been explained fully, I have created a new fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wxca0o78/

This is the exact source code I am currently using. As you can see on the rectangle, The bottom is not detected. If I add the centre square I get an issue too.

Comment: Edited my answer to address your last update. Check my answer and flag  it as accepted if it is what was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you are:

```
if (coordinates.y < height/2 && coordinates.y < width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y < coordinates.x) {
   alert("top triangle");
}

if (coordinates.x > width/2 && coordinates.y > width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y < coordinates.x) {
   alert("right triangle");
}

if (coordinates.y > height/2 && coordinates.y > width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y > coordinates.x) {
   alert("bottom triangle");
}

if (coordinates.x < width/2 && coordinates.y < width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y > coordinates.x) {
   alert("left triangle");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aocgrp06/2/

You exchanged x and y, x is horizontal and y is vertical.

EDIT:

There you are again:

```
if(coordinates.y > 0 && coordinates.y < height
   && coordinates.x > 0 && coordinates.x < width) {
    alert("center");
}
else if (coordinates.y < height/2 && coordinates.y < width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y < coordinates.x) {
    alert("top triangle");
}
else if (coordinates.x > width/2 && coordinates.y > width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y < coordinates.x) {
    alert("right triangle");
}
else if (coordinates.y > height/2 && coordinates.y > width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y > coordinates.x) {
    alert("bottom triangle");
}
else if (coordinates.x < width/2 && coordinates.y < width-coordinates.x && coordinates.y > coordinates.x) {
    alert("left triangle");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aocgrp06/7/

This works because your colored sectors are actually borders, so they are outside the element itself, hence the coordinates when you click on a colored sector are either negative or over the height or the width of the element.

EDIT 2:

You know, you should make sure your original algorithm is sound, before posting. I, as it usually happens, didn't check what apparently was working.

But your conditions were flawed and it showed when they failed when you moved from a square to a rectangle.

So, this is the mathematically correct code. Next time do your own work.

```
function getQuadrant(element, coordinates) {
    var width = element[0].offsetWidth;
    var height = element[0].offsetHeight;
    var r = height / width;

    reset(element);
    $('#x').text(coordinates.x);
    $('#y').text(coordinates.y);
    $('#w').text(width);
    $('#h').text(height);
    $('#r').text(r);

    var c1 = coordinates.y < (r * coordinates.x);
    var c2 = coordinates.y < ((r * -1 *  coordinates.x) + height);

    $('#c1').text(c1);
    $('#c2').text(c2);

    if (c1 && c2) {
        console.log("top triangle");
        element.addClass('tilt-up');
    }
    else if (c1 &&  !c2) {
        console.log("right triangle");
        element.addClass('tilt-right');
    }
    else if (!c1 && !c2) {
        console.log("bottom triangle");
        element.addClass('tilt-down');
    }
    else if (!c1 && c2) {
        console.log("left triangle");
        element.addClass('tilt-left');
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxca0o78/3/

I must note that the solution that I presented earlier was correct for the problem as you presented before and that in cases like this you should approve the answer and post a new follow-up question.

Comment: seems to work well. Is there a way of getting the center too?

Comment: @r3plica. see my answer for the center click

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I have updated my question with a new fiddle taking A. Rama's comment on board.

Comment: @r3plica what exactly you want.. explain the question once .. are you having a link inside box, or the box is itself a link

Comment: @r3plica.. if your box is itself an anchor `a`, it must work with my answer http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/aocgrp06/6/

Comment: @A.Rama, I see what you are saying with the borders which is why in my last update I added a box without borders. They are there just for the example. In my project, there are no borders. If you can tell me which solution works (currently neither work properly in my solution, but I suspect it is because of the borders) then I will gladly mark your solution as the answer :D

Comment: I don't see what would you want with a box without border, since it has no colored sector. However my solution let you vary the border size and automatically distinguishes the right sector or the center by means of the code I posted above (and it works even with a no border div, obviously in that case it's "all center").

Comment: There you are, my solution applied to your latest fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aocgrp06/8/

Comment: @A.Rama still not working as expected. You are so close. I have updated my question with my exact source code so you can see the problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to A. Rama's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28171216/3556874), because you need

> if the user clicks the center square, then it will add the center
>   class

http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/aocgrp06/4/

I added an extra element Div inside the box, which contains the whole height and width of the parent, this becomes the center of your box, which can be used to detect the click on the center.

```
<div id="box" style="border-top: 50px solid red;border-bottom: 50px solid #fc0;border-left: 50px solid blue;border-right: 50px solid green;font-size: 0px; line-height: 0%; width: 100px; height: 100px;"><div class='overlap'><div></div>


.overlap{
        background:#fff;;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
    }

 $('.overlap').click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        alert('center');
         $(this).addClass('center');

    });
```

The rest of your code is correct, just you need to interchange the left,right,top and bottom, in the code